# Watson visual-recognition training failed

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson, visual-recognition

I try to use visual-recognition of Watson IBM.
In the web visual-recognition i try to train my class but the trains failed.
I don't know what i am doing worng.
I upload 2 zip each one contains 30 jpg files of house photos.
After the uploading it is training but after some minutes it become red and failed.

In addition, I try to download the example training data of IBM (the Beagle) and it also faild.

Please help me notice what i am doing worng. 
Thanks,
Niv.

Comment: Try uploading using CURL. It should give you an error message. Make sure all your classes have at least 10 unique images.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of additional requirements regarding your training data. For instance the size of single pictures or entire file. Try to check your training data with this requirements:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/customizing.html#size-limitations

In addition its possible that your training statement has a syntax error.