# Errors with Watson Visual Recognition, training not possible

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am trying to train two models on Watson VR. One is for object (details) recognition within a picture. The other is to estimate the class object.
I have been able to prepare the classes of object for both models.
However, it seems I have multiple issues with training and I am now stack. I have found [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810422/watson-visual-recognition-training-failed) in Stack Overflow but it relates to data size and type; my data are all in .jpg format and all dataset is below 250 MB.

**Classifier:**
The classifier is the one that gives me more issues.
Firstly, I have tried to train the model but then the server went down. The day after I have found the model "trained" but with errors. I basically restarted by preparing again the classes.
All classes have at least 10-12 pictures (10 is minimum required). When I click on "Train Model" I receive the following error:

[image: ERROR 1]

In the dashboard I am given explanation of the failed training:

[image: ERROR 2]

Data size was originally about 241/250 MB, now it is 18.4/250 MB. I am not sure what brought the change.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the screenshots, that is very helpful!

It says your "DrinksClassifier" is in a failed state.  It's best to delete that collection from Studio, and start over.  Make sure you have at least 10 examples of each class... the lower screenshot seems to show it didn't find any examples for  "AgedCoffee".

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing!
I also noticed that but that is weird since the "AgedCoffee" class contains 11 examples. All classes include between 11 and 23 examples (including the "optional" negative class).